# Avoiding code repetition for MySQL queries (multiple while)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";

$question_01 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_01']);
// $question_02 - $question_09 go here...
$question_10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_10']);

    $i = 0;
    $array_sum=[];
     while ($i < 10){
      $i++;
       $sql =  "SELECT * FROM parteners WHERE question_no = 1 AND answer_variant = '$question_01'";
       $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

       $final_array_1 = array();

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
      {

        $final_array_1 = $row;
            $array_sum = array_map(function () {
                return array_sum(func_get_args());
            }, $array_sum, $final_array_1);
      }
}
print_r($final_array_1);
```

As you can see, I need to repeat the code for each $question_##. Is there a smarter way of doing this other than repeating the code? I'm not only concerned about turning everything into a code spaghetti but also about the efficiency of the operations as in loading times.

Let me know if you need clarification.

Update: Basically it should increase the value of "question_no" in the query until it reaches 10 and pick the corresponding $_POST value for each question.

Comment: so what is the problem? use `$i` to build the sql string inside the loop. Basic string concatenation.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I got the concatenation part. I was more interested into the looping process of this. Should I keep the two whiles?

Comment: `$sql =  "SELECT * FROM parteners ORDER BY question_no ASC LIMIT 10";`  check this in db directly and let me know showing desired output or not?

Comment: Not sure what is the result you want. Concatenation should be simpler, but you should try always use parameters instead http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: sql in loop ....low performance

Comment: @SporeDev what's the `array_map` part doing? Maybe you can tell more details about that, your goal, and how the data looks like?

Comment: @sidyll It's a questionaire that has an algorithm based on which it recommends you three winners out of 7 based on the points that they got on each question answer. The table has 10 columns: id, question_no, answer_variant and 7 that are holding the point values.

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh what other options do I have?

Comment: @SporeDev :use WHERE question_no IN(1,2,3.....) instead WHERE question_no = $i without loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways, variable variables or arrays. I'd suggest arrays as they are less prone to throwing errors everywhere.

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$questions = array();
$questions[1] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_01']);
// $question_02 - $question_09 go here...
$questions[10] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_10']);

    $i = 0;
    $array_sum=[];
     while ($i < 10){
      $i++;
       $sql =  "SELECT * FROM parteners WHERE question_no = $i AND answer_variant = '".$questions[$i]."'";
       $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

       $final_array_1 = array();

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
      {

        $final_array_1 = $row;
            $array_sum = array_map(function () {
                return array_sum(func_get_args());
            }, $array_sum, $final_array_1);
      }
}
print_r($final_array_1);
```

EDIT: The reason I used an array instead of just straight up using the POST variable in the while loop is so there is room before you run anything for validation (ensuring your question array contains 10 posted values etc)

Comment: when you do db queries from a loop use at least prepared statements to safe some of the overhead.

Comment: Agreed Radicarl, I was answering his question in terms on how to handle the passed POSTs, rather than fixing the entire code block. I would agree when they implement a solution, prepared statements are always the way to go

Answer (score 1):

First, to make your code modern and efficient, you should be using **PHP
Data Objects**, or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for short.  You will have access to prepared
statements,  which  are  made  exactly  for  this:  you  build  a  query
"template" and execute with different data, very efficiently and secure.

The loop is the proper way to  do it. Also, your `$questions` array is a
bit unecessary  since you can  retrieve data from `$_POST`  right inside
your loop. But if  you want to use it, there is no  need to "escape" the
string for  the database, since  it's handled by  PDO. So you  can build
your array in a easier way:

```
$questions = [
    $_POST['question_01'],
    $_POST['question_02'],
    $_POST['question_03'],
    # ...
    $_POST['question_10'],
];
```

Your loop with PDO:

```
$dbh = ... # create your database handle, connect to it
$st = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM parteners
    WHERE question_no = ? AND answer_variant = ?;
");

foreach (range(1, 10) as $i) {

    $result = $st->execute([ $i, $questions[$i-1] ]);
    # or, to build directly
    $result = $st->execute([
        $i, $_POST[ sprintf("question_%02d", $i) ]
    ]);

    $final_array[] = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

}

print_r($final_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would build one SQL-Statement which contains all questions and anwsers and do the rest with programming logic. SQL-Queries in a loop are a bad idea, because you have to do a lot of overhead for getting a task done, which the database server can do better. Also you should use prepared statements for performance and security.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM parteners WHERE (question_no = 1 AND answer_variant = ?) OR (question_no = 2 AND answer_variant = ?) OR (question_no = 3 AND answer_variant = ?) OR (question_no = 4 AND answer_variant = ?) OR (question_no = 5 AND answer_variant = ?) OR (question_no = 6 AND answer_variant = ?) OR (question_no = 7 AND answer_variant = ?) OR (question_no = 8 AND answer_variant = ?) OR (question_no = 9 AND answer_variant = ?) OR (question_no = 10 AND answer_variant = ?)" 
$stmt = myqli_prepare($query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssssss', $question_01, $question_02, $question_03,.....);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```